# Dropdownlist alternative in material UI of react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using `simple-menu` of material UI as shown in the [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h70e7?file=/demo.tsx). In my react app, I am displaying this menu in a primereact dialog.

However, my main requirement is to display a dropdown list in a dialog so that when a user selects something, it can be selected and I can do something based on that.
For example, if a user selects `Car`, I can see it selected. Also, I have some values associated with each entries.
For example, `Company` has value `0`,`Car` has value `1` and `Office` has value `2`.

So I am planning to have some buttons in the dialog so that after an item from the list is selected, and `Ok` button is selected, I can send the value associated with the selected item in a webservice call.

The closest I could find is simplelist:

https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#simple-list

But nothing close to Drowpdown list. Am I missing on something here?

More info:

The dialog looks like this:

[image]

And let's say, when I select an item, let's say, `Car`, it won't show `Car` but will display `Open Menu` which I am not looking for.

Comment: Yeah it's easy first make modal using material-ui then put the `simplelist` as the content of the modal

Comment: I added a screenshot of the dialog that I have and it's displaying the `Open Menu`. but it's not retaining the selected item as I mentioned above in my post. So you are saying that `simplelist` will not create this issue? Also, simple list won't show in a dropdown manner, right?

Comment: Like what do you want, the dialog should be open after selecting the option and should retain the selected option? If this is what you want I will post the code.

Comment: Not really. I already have a dialog when a user click on some button in the UI. Inside that I have the `Open Menu` button as mentioned in the codesandbox here (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h70e7?file=/demo.tsx). So, when I select something, the dropdown menu closes and doesn't show the selected item. Let me know if I can answer more questions. Thanks ! OR you could post your code and then I can let you know if there's some confusion.

Comment: did my solution work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have achieved is when the dropdown is opened and some option is selected then users can see what they have selected and dropdown doesn't close when some option is selected and in the console you can see what option is selected by index number.

You can follow this **code**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [visval, setVisval] = useState("Open Menu");

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    //console.log(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState();

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
    handleClose();
    //console.log(index);
    if (index === 0) {
      setVisval("Company");
    } else if (index === 1) {
      setVisval("Car");
    } else {
      setVisval("Office");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {visval}
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem
          data-my-value={1}
          selected={selectedIndex === 0}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
        >
          Company
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem
          data-my-value={2}
          selected={selectedIndex === 1}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
        >
          Car
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem
          data-my-value={3}
          selected={selectedIndex === 2}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
        >
          Office
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can checkout the updated and working [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fjqg3?file=/demo.tsx)

**EDIT :**

I have achieved what you asked i.e, the menu showing the three options should close when we select some option and the same should be visible in the place of `Open Menu`. But what I saw is that the code is no longer reusable and is becoming too large (I was aware of it).

**If you want your code to be minimised then follow the bellow suggestion**

**SUGGESTION :**
I saw that Material-ui's `autocomplete` just does the work with a clean code.
It gives you a set of options like a `dropdown menu` and when the user select's something the selected option is seen by the user.

[Link to the Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dkicr)

**You can migrate the same code into your dialog's content it will work fine.**

Comment: So when I am selecting something, it's not closing by itself as you mentioned. Is it possible to close it as well with the option that was selected as showing instead of Open Menu?

Comment: Yeah that's possible I am a bit busy right now so I will edit the answer with the updated code.

Comment: @Tan I have edited my answer (code,links) but what I see is that the code is not reusable anymore so I would recommend you to follow my suggestion that I have given in my answer else the code works fine.